# How to use a Babel script's object inside a Javascript?

Tags: javascript, module, babeljs, reactjs, referenceerror

I'm developing a ReactJS application using Babel/JSX syntax. I want to write an module made of React's components. But I cannot use objects of a babel script inside a Javascript the same way I could use objects of a Javascript inside another Javascript.

Html:

```
<script src="/js/react_babel_jsx.js" type="text/babel" ></script> 
<script src="/js/my_javascript.js"></script>
```

/js/react_babel_jsx.js:

```
var Test = function(){

    this.hello = function () {
         console.log('Hello!')
    }
}
```

/js/my_javascript.js

```
new Test().hello()
```

Console output in Chrome:

```
   my_javascript.js:3 Uncaught ReferenceError: Test is not defined
```

How could I use Babel script's objects inside a Javascript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Variables defined in the Babel script are wrapped in their own closure space. It's the same as this:

```
function BabelStuff () {
  var Test = function () {}
}

function OtherStuff () {
  var x = new Test() // Test not defined!
}
```

If you're just wanting to get past this problem right now you can add things to the `window` namespace.

```
window.Test = function(){
    this.hello = function () {
         console.log('Hello!')
    }
}
```

But this should only be for testing, not production applications. When you're ready to move on you'll want to transpile your code ahead of time. Here's a common boilerplate that can get you started https://github.com/gaearon/react-hot-boilerplate